# ¿Porque me aparece esto?

Tags: java, netbeans

como van, se que mi anterior pregunta no se entendio, pues vale la explico mejor, he creado un programa de Inventario de ventas, lo que pasa es que tengo un error con la conexion segun me dijo mi profesor del colegio, pero el no me puede ayudar por lo que busco ayuda aqui este es el siguiente mensaje que me aparece al agregar un producto nuevo a la Base de datos por medio del programa:

> Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is
>   not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+
>   requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit
>   option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using
>   SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need
>   either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set
>   useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate
>   verification.

---

Muchas gracias amigo, si solo le faltaba ese pedazo para que no me diera error en el SSL gracias.

Comment: Si la respuesta ayudo a solucionar el problema por favor marcarla como solución , revisa [tour], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En el mismo mensaje te da una posible solución a tu problema:

> You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting **useSSL=false**,
>   or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate
>   verification.

En tu cadena de conexión agrega ese parámetro:

```
jdbc:mysql://host:port/database?useSSL=false
```

De todas formas, si mal no recuerdo este mensaje es un Warning, no un error como tal, si aún sigues sin poder conectarte quizás sea otro el problema principal.